# Specialized Roubaix 2012 vs 2021 FujiSportif 1.1?

Tags: specialized-bikes, used-bike, upgrade-or-new-bike, new-rider, endurance

What is the tradeoff between a used Carbon bike vs a new aluminum bike? Would the answer be different if the carbon bike is less cost with better components?

Comment: Sorry, shopping advise is specifically off topic. If you could edit the question to make it generic about the advantages and disadvantages of new vs used bikes it would be on topic and might help with the answer you are looking for.  In the mean time have a search on this site for questions relating to aluminum vs carbon, disc vs rim brakes etc

Comment: Also likely a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17170/buying-a-used-higher-quality-bike-vs-a-lower-quality-new-bike

Comment: Honestly - ride them both and get the one you're most comfortable on.   We can't tell you which that will be.

Comment: If it was me, I would avoid 2nd hand carbon.  Probably over dramatic on my part and sure LBS has done all the checks but you really just never know what sort of treatment it's  had over that bikes' 10yr life

Comment: @Hursey: The same is true for aluminium or steel. From the outside you really can’t tell if it’s suffered from forces close to its yield strength (i.e. no plastic deformation) but it would greatly reduce its life time nonetheless.

Comment: @zuminskee Feel free to join [chat] to discuss - the Q&A is a bit formalised whereas chat is less structured.

Comment: The edit makes this a good question, but its now a duplicate of some existing questions like https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/79103/   and   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23283/